# Working with Android Bluetooth 4.0

Tags: android, bluetooth

I am developing an App which connects to heart rate sensor and retrives the values. I am using BLE 4.0.

With the help of google developer portal, I was able to build some code, but the app is crashing.

Please help me out. And also I need to sync the data which I have not able to able properly.

Code:

```
public class PollingTest extends Activity{

public Button btn2;

public static String UUID = "00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB";

public boolean mScanning;
public Handler mHandler;

public LeDeviceListAdapter mLeDeviceListAdapter;
public BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter;

static final int REQUEST_ENABLE_BT = 1;
public static final long SCAN_PERIOD = 10000;  // Stops scanning after 10 seconds.

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceStat){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceStat);
    setContentView(R.layout.pollingactivity);
    btn2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.pollB);
    final BluetoothManager bluetoothManager = (BluetoothManager) getSystemService(Context.BLUETOOTH_SERVICE);


    //mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();

    btn2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mHandler = new Handler();
            // Use this check to determine whether BLE is supported on the device.  Then you can
            // selectively disable BLE-related features.
            if (!getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_BLUETOOTH_LE)) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Bluetooth Low Energy is not supported on this Device ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                finish();
            }

            // Initializes a Bluetooth adapter.  For API level 18 and above, get a reference to
            // BluetoothAdapter through BluetoothManager.
            mBluetoothAdapter = bluetoothManager.getAdapter();

            // Checks if Bluetooth is supported on the device.
            if (mBluetoothAdapter == null) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Bluetooth not Supported", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                finish();
                return;
            }
            else {
                if (!mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
                    startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
                } else {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
                    startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
                    scanLeDevice(true);
                }
            }
        }
    });
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    // Ensures Bluetooth is enabled on the device.  If Bluetooth is not currently enabled,
    // fire an intent to display a dialog asking the user to grant permission to enable it.
    if (!mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
        if (!mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
            Intent enableBtIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
            startActivityForResult(enableBtIntent, REQUEST_ENABLE_BT);
        }
    }
}

protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    // User chose not to enable Bluetooth.
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_ENABLE_BT && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_CANCELED) {
        finish();
        return;
    }
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    scanLeDevice(false);
    //mLeDeviceListAdapter.clear();
}

private void scanLeDevice(final boolean enable) {
    if (enable) {
        // Stops scanning after a pre-defined scan period.
        mHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                mScanning = false;
                mBluetoothAdapter.stopLeScan(mLeScanCallback);
                invalidateOptionsMenu();
            }
        }, SCAN_PERIOD);

        mScanning = true;
        mBluetoothAdapter.startLeScan(mLeScanCallback);
    } else {
        mScanning = false;
        mBluetoothAdapter.stopLeScan(mLeScanCallback);
    }
    invalidateOptionsMenu();
}

private BluetoothAdapter.LeScanCallback mLeScanCallback = new BluetoothAdapter.LeScanCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onLeScan(final BluetoothDevice device, int rssi, byte[] scanRecord) {
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                //String macAddress;
                //macAddress = device.getAddress();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),device.getAddress(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                mLeDeviceListAdapter.addDevice(device);
                mLeDeviceListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                /*switch (device.getAddress().toUpperCase()){
                    case "8C:DE:52:64:8E:D1":
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "First",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }*/
            }
        });
    }
};

static class ViewHolder {
    TextView deviceName;
    TextView deviceAddress;
}

private class LeDeviceListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private ArrayList<BluetoothDevice> mLeDevices;
    private LayoutInflater mInflator;

    public LeDeviceListAdapter() {
        super();
        mLeDevices = new ArrayList<>();
        mInflator = PollingTest.this.getLayoutInflater();
    }

    public void addDevice(BluetoothDevice device) {
        if(!mLeDevices.contains(device)) {
            mLeDevices.add(device);
        }
    }

    public BluetoothDevice getDevice(int position) {
        return mLeDevices.get(position);
    }

    public void clear() {
        mLeDevices.clear();
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mLeDevices.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int i) {
        return mLeDevices.get(i);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int i) {
        return i;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        return null;
    }

}
```

}

Here I have commented onResume & onPause methods because,if dont,the app is getting crashed.

Log[image]

I think device in LeScan if not able to access/receive bluetooth object for some weird reason or something. Please help me out

Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because DeviceScanActivity.this returns 'null' (that pattern is likely not correctly set up), so when you call DeviceScanActivity.this.getLayoutInflater(), you get a NullPointerException, because you're trying to call getLayoutInflater() on something that does not exist.

Comment: I have refrenced it to PollingTest and yet I am getting the same error

Comment: Give me the exact code for how you changed `DeviceScanActivity.this.getLayoutInflater();`

Comment: Sorry man. As i told you, I did code with help of Google Dev portal. In that portal, the class was named 'DeviceScanActivity' . I should have changed 'DeviceScanActivity.this.getLayoutInflater();' to my class name .i.e., 'PollingTest.this.getLayoutInflater();' which I didnt not do.  [Here is the link ](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/development/+/7167a054a8027f75025c865322fa84791a9b3bd1/samples/BluetoothLeGatt/src/com/example/bluetooth/le/DeviceScanActivity.java) from which I did , Where they try to retrive devices and display on listView, but I want to retrieve and transfer data

Comment: Well is the exception you're getting still NullPointerException, or is it something else now?

Comment: Sir, I guess i have figured out the problem. Here, I am assigning both 'bluetoothManager ' & 'mBluetoothAdapter' in the onClickListner of btn2 and trying to access them outside of it. When I try to pass them outside, I am getting nullPointerException. So i tried declaring them outside onClickListner inside onCreate function and I get error to declare it as final which is not possible( as onResume & onPause needs to reassign mBluetoothAdapter.) SO HOW CAN I PASS BT OBJECT TO BOTH( everywhere) FROM INSIDE onClickListener of button

Comment: 1) Where do you instantiate mLeDeviceListAdapter? I can't find it anywhere. 2) You can take out the keyword final everywhere. Its not really necessary.

Comment: Its in the declaration above onCreate. Please help me. Need to scan for BT devices only when the user clicks on button which is not possible until I some how pass the BT object to everywhere in mmBluetoothAdapter

Comment: You are declaring it but your not instantiating it. You need to do new LeDeviceListAdapter () to instantiate it.

Comment: Ok. I missed that step. I have reinstantiated in onResume. But that does not solve problem. mmBluetoothAdapter  is still null

Comment: mBluetoothAdapter is visible to everything in the PollingTest class. All your other classes don't reference it. I think the only reason it's returning null, is because bluetoothManager.getAdapter() is returning null ( can't find an adapter). Is the "Bluetooth not supported" Toast showing up?

Comment: By they way, I might be wrong, but I don't think `mInflator = PollingTest.this.getLayoutInflater();` is not going to work, because you're calling it from outside PollingTest.

Comment: Can you suggest what to change here. I am out of options. I mean copy paste my code and change to what you think is working

Comment: I'm really sorry, I have not done what you're doing before so I really don't know what your main problem is. If bluetoothManager.getAdapter() is returning null, then that means it can not find an adapter, and that's your problem. If not, I need more information to find out what the problem is.

Comment: You should move mInflater and its related code back to PollingTest, thats where it belongs. Also the line above it should be `mLeDevices = new ArrayList<BluetoothDevice>();`